# How to fix Query Execution in when table name is like "Create/DeleteStatus" in SQL-Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

```
select count(*) from Create/DeleteStatus;
```

The above is the Table which is existed in my DB. It's also having some data. When I'm executing query it's giving error like,

Query execution failed

Reason:

> SQL Error [102] [42000]: Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Even If I used TILD symbol for the tabel, still it's giving error.

Query execution failed Reason:

> SQL Error [102] [42000]: Incorrect syntax near '`'.

I need to execute the query in Laravel Framework of PHP
Can any one tell how to execute above query?

Comment: What is your model called? Could you share some of your code that belongs to the table? Could you also tell why you need this naming? It's not possible to use `/` in your table names

Comment: $data= DB::table("Create/DeleteStatus")->get();
In this case I'm able to get data in from db using Laravel

Comment: You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: $data = DB::table('Create/DeleteStatus')
            ->join('user', 'Create/DeleteStatus.ID', '=', 'user.ID')
            ->select('user.ID','user.Name', 'Create/DeleteStatus.Mobile')
            ->whereBetween('Create/DeleteStatus.ID', [100, 200]) 
            ->get();

Comment: This way I'm able to get data in Laravel. No errors are comming. When I want to see the result using QUERY at SQL-Server, While preparing that query I'm facing issue. Thank you for all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to escape the table name:

```
select count(*) from `Create/DeleteStatus`;
```

Although using such table names is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah. But it's already existed with data. So I suppose not to rename.

Comment: @SivaK Maybe I'm wrong, but instead of facing pitfalls at the wrong time, it may be better to rename the table once and sleep well :) Especially, that later it will be much more difficult to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape table (and other object) names with square braces:

```sql
select count(*) from [Create/DeleteStatus];
-- Here -------------^-------------------^
```

Comment: Still getting same error.SQL Error [102] [42000]: Incorrect syntax near '`'.

Comment: @SivaK Oh, I see now the question was tagged incorrectly - it was tagged as [tag:mtsql], and now it's tagged with [tag:sql-server]. See my edited answer for this RDBMS.

Comment: Sorry @Mureinik. I suppose to tag with SQL-SERVER. But I did with 'MySql'